# Google Maps API Android wrong location in some devices

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that uses Google Maps API and in some devices like Huawei Rio - L03 and Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime sets a wrong location, but in others like Motorola Moto X, HTC Desire 626 it works correctly

Someone knows why?

I really need help :( If need some code tell me

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

//Remove location updates for only set it one time
if (gpsSettings.mGoogleApiClient != null)            
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(gpsSettings.mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```

Comment: wheres the code?

Answer (score 0):

try adjust the interval and priority

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); //
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); //
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY); //

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```